# Why is the time complexity of creating a heap array not O(log(n!)) instead of O(nlogn)?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, heap, heapsort

Insertion of a new element in a heap through an insert function "insert(A,n)" takes O(log n) time (where n is the number of elements in array 'A'). The insert function is given below:

```
void insert(int A[], int n)
{
   int temp,i=n;
   cout<<"Enter the element you want to insert";
   cin>>A[n];
   temp=A[n];
   while(i>0 && temp>A[(i-1)/2])
   {
      A[i]=A[(i-1)/2];
      i=(i-1)/2;
   }
   A[i]=temp;
}
```

The time complexity for the insert function is O(log n).

A function that will convert an array to a heap array is given as:

```
void create_heap()
{
   int A[50]={10,20,30,25,5,6,7};
   //I have not taken input in array A from user for simplicity.
   int i;
   for(i=1;i<7;i++)
   {
      insert(A,i);
   }
}
```

It was given that the time complexity of this function is O(nlogn).

-> But the insert function has a maximum 'i' of elements to compare in each call. I.e., the time complexity in a single run of the loop is O(log i) for each call.

-> So first it's log1, then log2, then log3 and so on till log6.

-> So for n elements of an array, the total time complexity would be
log2 + log3 + log4 +....logn

-> This will be log(2x3x4x...xn) = log(n!)

**So why is the time complexity not O(log(n!)) but O(nlogn) ??**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Log(n!) Is bounded by log(n^n) from log rules its n*logn

```
1*2*3*4*....*n = n!
n*n*n*n*....*n = n^n
```

Clearly n! < n^n

Then why use `O(nlogn)` when `O(logn!)` is a tighter bound? because `nlogn` is bounded by log(n!), surprising, is it not?

```
log(1*2*3*4*....*n) = log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n)
```

Let's throw away first half

```
log(1*2*3*4*....*n) > log(n/2) + log((n/2) + 1) + log((n/2)+2) + ... + log(n) 
                    > log(n/2) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2) 
                    = n/2*log(n/2) = O(nlogn)
```

[image]

Comment: Does that mean there is nothing wrong in my analysation?

Comment: @Avi nothing wrong in your analisys. Writing it as O(nlogn) is also correct as log(n!) Is bounded by log(n^n) which is nlogn.

Comment: @TonyTannous hope my edit makes it a bit more clear (and hope it is correct :))